# PIL: converting an image with mode "I" to "RGB" results in a fully white image

Tags: png, python-imaging-library, zlib

The image at the end of this question is a PNG with mode I, which stands for Indexed, as far as I can tell.

I'm trying to create a thumbnail out of it, and save it as JPG with PIL.

However, is I leave the `mode` alone, PIL won't let me resize it with error `unable to generate thumbnail: cannot write mode I as JPEG.`

If I convert it to `RGB`, the result will be a fully white image.

Is there a way to fix this?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2d1edk2iu4ixk25/NGC281.png

Comment: Hmm - "the image" is a JPEG. Any chance of showing the actual image? (As the problem might be with the original PNG.) If you convert Indexed to RGB using PIL, (1) is the converted image still okay? and (2) does it work if you use other software to convert the image to RGB?

Comment: Hi, StackOverflow converted my image when I uploaded. I edited the question providing a link to Dropbox. Your answers: (1) no, the indexed file, when converted to RGB, becomes completely white; (2) yes, it worked with Gimp.

Comment: Can you try one more manual step? The input file is 16 bit, grayscale. Convert it to 8 bit and run your original code with that. If it works, the problem lies in PIL. "Grayscale" is the same as "indexed", in 8 bit mode (256 tints of gray). Perhaps that's the underlying issue here.

Comment: Thanks. So I converted it like this, and it worked: `table = [i/256 for i in range(65536)]; im = im.point(table, 'L')` - what does it mean?`If possible, I'd rather not lose depth of the image by lowering the bit  depth.

Comment: If you got it working this way, I wouldn't worry about the lower quality. It's for displaying a thumbnail, right? Downscaling to a smaller size *and* saving as a JPEG does far more damage.

Comment: Yeah but I'm using it also for the high res thumbnail (imagine a user uploading an image that's 4000x4000 pixels, and I'm saving a thumbnail that's 1920 pixels wide for displaying in HD resolution. That should still look good enough. Anyway, I'll put a warning message that Indexed PNGs might result in loss of quality and call it a day :-) Thanks for your help! Please post your solution as an answer so I may accept it.

Comment: PIL mode I is for "32-bit integer pixels" not Indexed. "Indexed" mode in PIL would be "P (8-bit pixels, mapped to any other mode using a colour palette)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input image is a 16-bit grayscale PNG, and it appears PIL has a problem with this. Manually converting it to an 8-bit image before further processing makes it work again.

The problem *may* originate inside PIL itself. The [PyPNG](http://pythonhosted.org/pypng/ca.html) homepage asserts

> ..PIL only has internal representations (PIL mode) for 1-bit and 8-bit channel values. This makes me wonder if PIL can read PNG files with bit depth 2 or 4 (greyscale or palette), and also bit depth 16 (which PNG supports for greyscale and RGB images).

Then again, that page is from 2009. It could be worth tracking down where PIL is maintained from, and report this as a bug (? Or possibly a feature request?).