# Python image conversion

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am trying to convert that has the mode I (32-bit signed integer pixels) into a standard greyscale or 'RGB' image. The problem is when I try to convert it, it just becomes a blank white image. I am using the PIL Module.

There is the image I am trying to convert.

[image]

```
from PIL import Image
sample_img = Image.open('sample.png') 
sample_img=sample_img.convert('L')
```

Comment: Can you show your non-working code?

Comment: Perhaps [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892919/pil-converting-an-image-with-mode-i-to-rgb-results-in-a-fully-white-image) will help. It deal with a similar problem, but with a 16-bit grayscale PNG.

Comment: @Yuriko this is also a 16-bit grayscale PNG, and this question probably should have been closed as a duplicate. The correct answer is lurking in the comments to the other question: using the `point` function with a proper table. `sample_img = sample_img.point([i//256 for i in range(0x10000)], 'L')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

sample_img = Image.open('sample.png') 
rescaled = 255 * np.asarray(sample_img)/2**16
img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(rescaled))
```

Which gives:

```
>>> np.asarray(img)

array([[ 95,  96,  98, ...,  98, 105, 107],
       [ 93,  97,  99, ..., 100, 105, 108],
       [ 94,  99, 100, ..., 102, 105, 110],
       ..., 
       [130, 125, 125, ...,  97,  98, 100],
       [128, 120, 123, ...,  99,  99, 101],
       [125, 119, 120, ..., 101, 100, 101]], dtype=uint8)
```

Which is a 'standard' 8-bit grayscale image.

Answer (score 1):

PIL is one of the buggiest packages I have ever tried to rely on. This is a very straight-forward conversion, and the sample code you give should just work.

Here's a work-around.

```
def ItoL(im):
    w, h = im.size
    result = Image.new('L', (w, h))
    pix1 = im.load()
    pix2 = result.load()
    for y in range(h):
        for x in range(w):
            pix2[x,y] = pix1[x,y] >> 8
return result
```

Comment: Both of these solutions works but I found that the other one was more suited for my code.